# I trying to convert a string to output looking a certain way using the replace but having issues

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to convert a string to output looking a certain way and I figured the best way to do it was using pattern matching but I'm running into some issues. I don't want to break the string down and then concatenated it.  I was hoping there was a simpler way. I'm also having an issue with (id) it seems that the string literal after (id,)lastname is taking on the replacement value

```
var myFunction - function(){
var str = "id,created,employee(id,firstname,employeeType(id),    lastname),location"; 

var str2="id, created, employee";
var str3 = "(id,firstname,employeeType";
var str4="(id)";
var str5 ="lastname)";
var str6 = "location";


var test = str2.replace(/[,]/g, '<br>\r\n').split(",");
var test1 = str3.replace(/[(/,]/g, '<br>-\r\n').split(",");
var test2 =str4.replace(/[()/,]/g, '<br />--\r\n').split(",");
var test3 = str5.replace(/[,/)]/g, '<br />').split(",");
var test4 = str6.replace(/[)/,]/g, '<br />').split(",");

var result =test +  test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 ;
var match = result.split(',')     

 document.getElementById("myDemo").innerHTML = match.join("<br />");;
 }
myFunction()
```

My output looks like below

```
 id
 created
 employee
 - id
 - firstname
 - employeeType
 -- id
 -- lastname  this should only be one dash not two
 location
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that walks through the string one character as a time.  When either `(` or `)` are encountered, a counter is incremented or decremented that indicates how many preceding `-` characters there should be.

```
var stringFormatter = function() {
  var str = "id,created,employee(id,firstname,employeeType(id),    lastname),location"; 

  var formatted = '';
  var indentCount = 0;
  var chars = str.split('');

  chars.forEach(function(char) {
    if (char == '(') {
      indentCount++;
    } else if (char == ')') {
      indentCount--;
    }
    if (char == ',' || char == '(') {
      formatted = formatted.concat('<br/>');
      for (var i = 0; i < indentCount; i++ ) {
        formatted = formatted.concat('-');
      }
    } else if (char != '(' && char != ')') {
      formatted = formatted.concat(char);
    }
  });

  document.getElementById("myDemo").innerHTML = formatted;
}

stringFormatter();
```

The output looks like:

```
id
created
employee
-id
-firstname
-employeeType
--id
- lastname
location
```

Answer (score 0):

For any nesting level you can use this

```
var myFunction = function(){
var str = "id,created,employee(id,firstname,employeeType(id),    lastname),location"; 

while(/\([^()]+\)/g.test(str))
{
    m = /\(([^()]+)\)/g.exec(str);
    m[1] = m[1].replace(/(-+)/g,"-$1");
    m[1] = m[1].replace(/,/g,"-");
    str = str.replace(/\(([^()]+)\)/,'-'+m[1]);
}

str = str.replace(/,/g,'<br>\r\n');
str = str.replace(/(-+)/g,'<br>$1 \r\n');

document.getElementById("myDemo").innerHTML += str + '</br>';

 }
myFunction();
```

Output:

```
id
created
employee
- id
- firstname
- employeeType
-- id
- lastname
location
```

See the result for more nesting level

```
var str = "id,created,employee(id,firstname,contact(Mobile,Landline(home,office)),employeeType(id),    lastname),location"; 
...
```

Output:

```
id
created
employee
- id
- firstname
- contact
-- Mobile
-- Landline
--- home
--- office
- employeeType
-- id
- lastname
location
```